# LM vs PLM results in panel data estimation

Tags: r, least-squares, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, lm

I'm estimating the effect of immigration on different house prices using panel data, I'm using a simple OLS model with fixed effects. I ran an `lm` function before running a `plm` the problem is that the `lm` produces more significant coefficients with higher values or R^2.

I know the theory says that I need to remove any area and time fixed effects but after estimating the model it seems that I don't need to. which one should I choose?

the first result is the one for the `lm` model while the second is for the `plm`.

```
==================================================================================================
                                                               Dependent variable:                
                                               ---------------------------------------------------
                                                    LB           LD           LF           LH     
                                                   (1)          (2)          (3)          (4)     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
`Ratio Immigrants/pop t-1`                       2.457***     4.084***     3.017***     5.535***  
                                                 (0.052)      (0.114)      (0.072)      (0.113)   

`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-1`          0.000***    0.00000***    0.000***     0.000***  
                                                 (0.000)      (0.000)      (0.000)      (0.000)   

`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-1`  -0.045***    -0.067***    -0.021***    -0.061***  
                                                 (0.001)      (0.002)      (0.001)      (0.002)   

Constant                                         6.161***    11.842***     6.623***    12.274***  
                                                 (0.008)      (0.018)      (0.011)      (0.018)   

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                                      2,739        2,739        2,739        2,739    
R2                                                0.688        0.535        0.528        0.617    
Adjusted R2                                       0.688        0.534        0.527        0.616    
Residual Std. Error (df = 2735)                   0.143        0.315        0.200        0.312    
F Statistic (df = 3; 2735)                     2,010.415*** 1,047.706*** 1,019.035*** 1,467.477***
==================================================================================================
Note:                                                                  *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01






======================================================================================
                                                         Dependent variable:          
                                               ---------------------------------------
                                                  LB        LD        LF        LH    
                                                  (1)       (2)      (3)       (4)    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
`Ratio Immigrants/pop t-1`                     0.596***  1.170***  0.970***  0.834*** 
                                                (0.104)   (0.274)  (0.209)   (0.174)  

`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-1`        0.000***    0.000    0.000   0.00000***
                                                (0.000)   (0.000)  (0.000)   (0.000)  

`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-1` 0.010***  0.030***  -0.006**  0.009*** 
                                                (0.001)   (0.004)  (0.003)   (0.002)  

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                                     2,739     2,739    2,739     2,739   
R2                                               0.049     0.045    0.010     0.046   
Adjusted R2                                     -0.114    -0.119    -0.159    -0.118  
F Statistic (df = 3; 2337)                     40.014*** 36.452*** 8.186*** 37.679*** 
======================================================================================
Note:                                                      *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

.

```
B1 <- data$LB ~ data$`Ratio Immigrants/pop t-1` + data$`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-1` + data$`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-1`
D1 <- data$LD ~ data$`Ratio Immigrants/pop t-1` + data$`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-1` + data$`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-1`
F1 <- data$LF ~ data$`Ratio Immigrants/pop t-1` + data$`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-1` + data$`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-1`
H1 <- data$LH ~ data$`Ratio Immigrants/pop t-1` + data$`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-1` + data$`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-1`


B2 <- data$LB ~ data$`Ratio Immigrants/pop t-2` + data$`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-2` + data$`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-2`
D2 <- data$LD ~ data$`Ratio Immigrants/pop t-2` + data$`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-2` + data$`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-2`
F2 <- data$LF ~ data$`Ratio Immigrants/pop t-2` + data$`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-2` + data$`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-2`
H2 <- data$LH ~ data$`Ratio Immigrants/pop t-2` + data$`Disposable income in Thousand EUR t-2` + data$`Unemployment rate on all civilian income t-2`

#################
#OLS
#################

r_OLSB1 <- lm(B1,data = data)
r_OLSD1 <- lm(D1,data = data)
r_OLSF1 <- lm(F1,data = data)
r_OLSH1 <- lm(H1,data = data)

r_OLSB2 <- lm(B2,data = data)
r_OLSD2 <- lm(D2,data = data)
r_OLSF2 <- lm(F2,data = data)
r_OLSH2 <- lm(H2,data = data)

stargazer::stargazer(r_OLSB1,r_OLSD1,r_OLSF1,r_OLSH1, type = "text")

stargazer::stargazer(r_OLSB2,r_OLSD2,r_OLSF2,r_OLSH2, type = "text")

# ran a simple ols regression without removing any area or time fixed effects, this is just for refrence
# the results from the normal ols model will not be considered as a true effect but will act as a refrence
# for the other regressions

#################
plotmeans(data$LH ~ data$Year, data = data)

plotmeans(data$LH ~ data$`District code`, data = data)

#################
#Fixed-Effects
#################

r_FEB1 <- plm(B1, model = "within", effect = "twoways", data = data)
r_FED1 <- plm(D1, model = "within", effect = "twoways", data = data)
r_FEF1 <- plm(F1, model = "within", effect = "twoways", data = data)
r_FEH1 <- plm(H1, model = "within", effect = "twoways", data = data)

r_FEB2 <- plm(B2, model = "within", effect = "twoways", data = data)
r_FED2 <- plm(D2, model = "within", effect = "twoways", data = data)
r_FEF2 <- plm(F2, model = "within", effect = "twoways", data = data)
r_FEH2 <- plm(H2, model = "within", effect = "twoways", data = data)

stargazer::stargazer(r_FEB1,r_FED1,r_FEF1,r_FEH1, type = "text")

stargazer::stargazer(r_FEB2,r_FED2,r_FEF2,r_FEH2, type = "text")



# ran a fixed effect model using the plm function
# used the within specificationa with a twoways effect to capture both area and time fixed effects
# although these regresssions 

#################
```

Comment: Hi. Can you share the R code you ran? We need to know more than the functions you used. The `plm()` function has many different applications.

Comment: There is test to choose between an FE-panel and OLS - Breusch-Pagan's LM-test for pooling. It is implemented in ```plm```

Comment: I have just added the code

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the documentation how to use the formula interface of lm/plm first. Then re-run your analysis.

Comment: Thank you for providing the code. What criteria did you use to determine that you *don’t* (or may not) need unit or time fixed effects? Theory? In general, running a pooled model is a bit naive, but each situation is different.

Comment: From what I know a model that has a larger R2 is better because it's a better fit. But I guess it's not the most important aspect because the lm model is biased while the plm is unbiased. Is that right?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can run a ‘pooled’ ordinary least squares regression using the `plm` package. To be clear, the `plm` package has several tests to help you determine if a ‘pooled’ model is appropriate given your data. Have you conducted any tests thus far?

Comment: I've conducted a `pFtest`

Comment: So what is your question specifically?